# Import pysmile_license

Tags: python-2.7, smile

I am using pysmile in Python 2.7. When I run the .py file for the first time I need to import the library and the license that SMILE needs. The first time it runs okay. But after that, it says that the license has been already initialized and I can't run the file anymore. Do you know the correct way to import pysmile and its license. I am working with academic version.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, Karla. It's always helpful if you can provide more details. For example, the code you wrote or screenshots of error messages. Are you trying to import the license every time you import the package? I'm not familiar with this package, but I'm guessing you should need to do that only the first time.

Comment: Thank you. This actually worked. I have to include the license the first time I run the code, for future runnings I have to omit the license line.